# Matching rows across tables for R

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to match data across two tables through two columns in R: ID number & address. I'm primarily matching through ID number, but there is missing data so address is the back-up column for matching. Any ideas on how to do it? Does merge() allow an "or" in the "by" argument?

`left_join` to get the ones that match then filter out missing data & repeat

This doesn't work but for instance:

```
merge(table1, table2, by = 'ID number' or 'address')
```

is too long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to merge twice - first with `id` and then with `address` - and then clean up the final values -

```
table1 <- data.frame(
  id = c(1, 2, 3),
  address = letters[1:3],
  stringsAsFactors = F
)

table2 <- data.frame(
  id = c(1, NA_integer_, 3),
  address = c(letters[1:2], NA_character_),
  value = 10:12,
  stringsAsFactors = F
)

d <- merge(table1, table2[c("id", "value")], by = "id", all.x = T)
result <- merge(d, table2[c("address", "value")], by = "address", all.x = T)
result$final_value <- with(result, ifelse(is.na(value.x), value.y, value.x))

  address id value.x value.y final_value
1       a  1      10      10          10
2       b  2      NA      11          11
3       c  3      12      NA          12
```

With `dplyr` -

```
table1 %>% 
  left_join(select(table2, id, value), by = "id") %>% 
  left_join(select(table2, address, value), by = "address") %>% 
  mutate(
    final_value = coalesce(value.x, value.y)
  )

  id address value.x value.y final_value
1  1       a      10      10          10
2  2       b      NA      11          11
3  3       c      12      NA          12
```